# Ротация логов с помощью logrotate

Tags: linux

помогите разобраться с ротацией логов томката.
Настроил на сервере logrotation.conf, добавив в него

```
/usr/local/tomcat9/logs {
   daily
   rotate 7
   size 10M
   compress
   missingok
   delaycompress
   dateext
}
```

Далее выполняю команду `logrotate -d /etc/logrotate.conf`, но ничего не происходит. Если взять по одному файлу, то почему-то он не архивирует их, а просто переименовывает

```
renaming /usr/local/tomcat9/logs/catalina.out to /usr/local/tomcat9/logs/catalina.out-20191004
creating new /usr/local/tomcat9/logs/catalina.out mode = 0777 uid = 1001 gid = 1001
```

Помогите пожалуйста понять, как сделать правильно, чтобы он всю папку логов просмотрел.

Comment: Ну он вроде и не должен архивировать потому что delaycompress стоит?

Comment: я его убирал, все равно. Мне просто не понятно, он должен файл вообще запихивать в архив или нет. Я просто делал по статье https://losst.ru/nastrojka-logrotate#_Logrotate-2 и у него сразу он в gz файлы перевел

Comment: второй вопрос, никак не связанный с первым, я удалил. задайте его, пожалуйста, отдельно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> выполняю команду `logrotate -d /etc/logrotate.conf`, но ничего не происходит

опция `-d` — это как раз указание «**ничего не делать**, только вывести отладочные сообщения».

впрочем, и запуск **без** этой опции не приведёт к тому, чего вы, вероятно, ожидаете: файлы не будут ротироваться при каждом запуске. программа ведёт учёт ротаций (обычно в файле `/var/lib/logrotate/status` — уточните в man-странице вашего дистрибутива). поэтому ротировать чаще, чем вы указали директивами в конф. файле, она, конечно, не будет.

> не архивирует их, а просто переименовывает

программа *logrotate* не обучена архивировать. она умеет (цитата из заголовка man-страницы) ротировать (то, что вы назвали «переименовывает»), сжимать и отправлять по почте.

конечно, ещё она умеет вызывать описанные в секции скрипты: а) в самом начале обработки секции — `firstaction`, б) перед ротацией файла — `prerotate`, в) после ротации файла — `postrotate` и г) в конце обработки секции — `lastaction`.

вот в скриптах — да, можно вызвать и архиватор.

вы упомянули директиву `compress` — благодаря ей ротированные файлы будут сжиматься. вы также упомянули опцию `delaycompress` — при **первой** ротации файл не будет сжиматься, только при второй.

> чтобы он всю папку логов просмотрел

программа *logrotate* этому не обучена. никакого рекурсивного поиска она не осуществляет.

ей нужно указывать файлы — конкретные имена, или подпадающие под указанную маску.

если маска слишком «широка» — `*`, то надо использовать директиву `olddir`, куда программа будет перемещать ротируемые файлы (если не указать, и уже ротированные файлы останутся в том же каталоге, где и исходные, то будут повторно ротированы при следующем запуске).

---

доп. чтение:

```
$ man logrotate.conf
```

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ. Судя по плюсам, тема довольно популярна) Но у меня еще вопрос, относительно имени файла ротации, это верно, что у меня он к расширению пишет дату ? catalina.out-20191004

Answer (score 2):

Если забыть про `-d`, о которой длинно написано в другом ответе, то первая проблема у вас с `delaycompress`. Эту проблему нельзя назвать проблемой так как это вы делаете правильно.

Директива `delaycompress` указывает logrotate не сжимать файлы сразу. Сжатие означает что файл будет сжат в другой файл, и затем удалён. Теперь вопрос: что будет если файл всё ещё открыт программой, которая туда пишет логи? Программа продолжит писать логи в удалённый файл, но стоит программе этот файл закрыть, как все записанные туда с момента удаления данные уйдут в небытие. Потом вы будете удивляться дыркам в логах. Потому вы делаете правильно что инструктируете logrotate не сжимать файлы сразу.

Что вы не делаете, так это вы не сообщаете вашему демону что ему нужно переоткрыть файлы логов (обычно сигналом `HUP`). Это означает что вы всё равно можете столкнуться с такой ситуацией, как выше.

Альтернативно можно использовать директиву `copytruncate`, но здесь вы опять получаете риск потери логов.

Comment: Вы не могли бы мне подсказать, вот такой скрипт будет ли работать корректно ? /usr/local/tomcat9/logs/*.txt, /usr/local/tomcat9/logs/*.log, /usr/local/tomcat9/logs/*.out, { daily rotate 7 start 0 size 10M missingok delaycompress copytruncate }. Мне оказывается не надо архивировать файлы. Будут ли они автоматом удалены после 7й ротации? Я никак не могу это протестировать.